# Connecting to tightvncserver shows brown screen and cursor and nothing else with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, vnc-server, vnc-viewer, tightvnc

I am trying to connect to a server and installed tightvnc server on it following these steps :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers#Customising_your_session

And hence my xstartup file looks like this:

```
cat .vnc/xstartup 
#!/bin/sh

# Change "GNOME" to "KDE" for a KDE desktop, or "" for a generic desktop
MODE="GNOME"

#Uncommment this line if using Gnome and your keyboard mappings are incorrect.
#export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1

# Load X resources (if any)
if [ -e "$HOME/.Xresources" ]
then
        xrdb "$HOME/.Xresources"
fi

# Try a GNOME session, or fall back to KDE
if [ "GNOME" = "$MODE" ]
then
        if which gnome-session >/dev/null
        then
                gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d &
        else
                MODE="KDE"
        fi
fi

# Try a KDE session, or fall back to generic
if [ "KDE" = "$MODE" ]
then
        if which startkde >/dev/null
        then
                startkde &
        else
                MODE=""
        fi
fi

# Run a generic session
if [ -z "$MODE" ]
then
        xsetroot -solid "#DAB082"
        x-terminal-emulator -geometry "80x24+10+10" -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
        x-window-manager &
fi
```

And when I try to connect to the server it shows brown screen like this :
[image: Dev server Connection using remmina client]

Permissions on xstartup are :

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user user  943 May 19 06:35 xstartup*
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on both the systems . Could you please help me out

Comment: Am having similar issues. Did you find solution? I got it working with xfce4 but had a different issue. I can post info if interested.

Comment: The brown color comes from the line
xsetroot -solid "#DAB082"
which sets the background color of the window.
Have you tried setting up VINO instead?  See more [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers).

Answer (score -2):

Install Desktop in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop gnome-panel gnome-settings-daemon metacity nautilus gnome-terminal
```

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop gnome-panel gnome-settings-daemon metacity nautilus gnome-terminal
```

There are different Desktop present.

Unity:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

KDE:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

MATE:

```
sudo apt-get install mate-desktop
```

Gnome:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

XFCE(XUBUNTU):

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

Reboot that System, and try again.